# Действие в unity3d пока нажата клавиша

Tags: unity3d, mobile-development

Здравствуйте!
На сцене имеется кнопка. Так вот, как сделать, чтобы пока я держу нажатой кнопку, то постепенно прибавлялось какое-либо значение, а при отпускании это значение плавно уменьшалось?
Что-то похожее имеется в гоночных играх: пока нажата клавиша вперёд, у машины увеличивается скорость, а при отпускании клавиши скорость машины постепенно уменьшается.

Comment: @stepofchange, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заводим переменную отвечающую за скорость увеличения параметра в секунду.

```
public class FlightScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public float VelocityForward = 1.0f; // скорость перемещения за секунду
    public float MaxPower = 4f; //максимальная мощность
    private float power = 0.3f; // текущая мощность
    public bool isPress = false; //флаг что кнопка нажата


    void Update () 
    {
        power += Input.GetAxis("Power") * Time.deltaTime * (isPress ? 1: -1);// расчитываем прирост мощности с учетом прошедшего времени и состояния кнопки
        power = Mathf.Clamp(power, 0.0f, MaxPower); //ограничиваем максимальной       
        Target.position += VelocityForward * Target.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * power * Time.deltaTime; //смещаем объект используя новую мощность
    }
```

}

Когда нажимают кнопку меняете значение `isPress` и получаете разгон либо торможение.